# 2009 Chevy Malibu is dead, no crank, no clicking sound, no lights turning on inside. Just completely dead

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, malibu, no-crank-no-start

I need help. My 2009 Chevy Malibu was working fine, the next day I was going to turn it on, it didn't. There was no crank, no clicking, no lights inside turning on. Nothing, just dead. I have replaced the battery, the alternator and have checked the fuse box and relays and those are working fine. What can it be? Any input is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Use a multimeter to check if you have power to the fuse box.

Comment: "*I have replaced the battery, the alternator and have checked the fuse box and relays and those are working fine*"  It is  still completely unresponsive AFTER you did all that?

Comment: @AlaskaMan, yes, after all that it is still unresponsive.

Comment: Have you checked _all_ the relays? I believe your vehicle has three fuse boxes - one in the engine, one in the passenger floor well, and one in the trunk. The ignition relay located in your engine compartment fuse box might be bad. A good trick is to just swap it with another relay in the box, and see if it magically starts working. (Just making sure you've checked that one specifically.)

Comment: Have you checked the electrical integrity of the big battery cables and the condition of the cables' connectors? A cable might be broken internally, and given the car's age, might well have degraded connectors or bad cable-to-connector joints.

Comment: How did you check your fuses? Just by checking (looking)? Did you try a parasitic draw test?